# How to make an view showed up from the right side to left in iOs?

Tags: ios, objective-c

the view is out of screen, I know how to make the view from left to right, but on the contrary, I'm not sure what's the original coordinate of the view if it come from the right side

```
rightImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
rightImage.size = CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth*5/9, kScreenHeight*5/12);
CGPoint rightImageCenter = rightImage.center;
rightImageCenter.x += kScreenWidth + 100;
rightImageCenter.y = kScreenHeight * 0.6;
rightImage.center = rightImageCenter;


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        rightCenter.x -= 200;
        rightCenter.y += kScreenHeight*0.6;
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
        rightImage.image=image;
        rightImage.center = rightCenter;
        label.text = arr[1];
 } completion:nil];
```

Comment: what you exactly want? write sufficient details. not getting your question properly

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @lion，There is a view out of the screen , I want to make an animation  and move view from the right side to left

Comment: @rahulroy9202 , there is part of code I edited

Comment: Out of screen means ? it's x position is higher then screen width like so?

Comment: yes, x position is larger than the screen width. and it should be the right side of the screen@Lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am doing in my one case is,

Appearing right to left

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

 // [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];  // I am using autolayout!
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                 animations:^ {


                     CGRect frame = self.sideMenu.frame;
                     frame.origin.x = myX;
                     self.sideMenu.frame = frame;
                     self.sideMenu.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

// [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
// [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.3];
// [UIView commitAnimations];
                 }];




}
```

and when it is disappear something like below,

```
- (IBAction)sideMenuClick:(id)sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                 animations:^ {
                     CGRect frame = self.sideMenu.frame;
                     frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width;
                     self.sideMenu.frame = frame;
                     self.sideMenu.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     //                         [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                     //                         [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.3];
                     //                         [UIView commitAnimations];
                     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                 }];

 }
```

Avoid commented code!!

Here `side menu` is `UIView` which moves from right to left.

`myX` should be counted in `viewDidload` like,

```
   myX = self.view.frame.size.width - self.sideMenu.frame.size.width;
```

And `side menu`'s initial position (means x = screen width i.e. self.view.frame.size.width).

You can manage your scenario according to your need something like i have done in my case

Hope this will help :)